# Est-il convenable d'utiliser « et ce sur tous les plans » dans un email formel?

Tags: grammaire, expressions, registre

À l'oral, j'ai à plusieurs reprises entendu ladite expression, même en milieu professionnel:

> Je suis à votre entière disposition pour n'importe quel service lié à
>   l'informatique, et ce sur tous les plans.

Je me demande si ce genre de phrase est acceptable dans un email formel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oui, tu peux le dire. "et ce, sur tous les plans" est plus juste :)